# Trying to delay an animation on startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have:

```
$(window).one('load',function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.slider').slideToggle('slow'),
        15000 
    });
});
```

I'm trying to limit the animation to only once so as not to get annoying.
The problem is: it's not waiting 15 seconds.  It animates immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually surprised that this compiles (or rather, does not yell at you) -- you misplaced a '`}`'.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.slider').slideToggle('slow')
    }, // <-- right there!
    15000 
);// <-- not there!
```

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn Why do you say that?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).one('load',function() {
    setTimeout(
        function(){$('.slider').slideToggle('slow')},
        15000 
    );
});
```

Comment: this is very subtle difference and i almost didnt catch it. you should add a quick explanation so its clear what you've corrected

Answer (score 1):

The comma is in the wrong place.

The time is a parameter from `setTimeout` function

```
$(window).one('load',function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
           $('.slider').slideToggle('slow');
        },
      15000);
});
```